# How to receive a BLE message in various packets?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm receiving Bluetooth messages (characteristics) in my Android method:

```
public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) { }
```

But messages sent are splitted in various packets.

For example, a device sends:

```
80 50 30 14 23 14 26 22
```

But I receive in onCharacteristicChanged:

```
80 50 30
```

And then:

```
14 23 14 26 22
```

How can I do to get the entire message? (The length and number of the packets may change)

Comment: Rely on your own implementation of messaging. For example, send a message_end byte (lets say 0x03) to inform other side that the transfer of an entire message is completed.